# How to debug rust static library called from c++

Tags: c++, rust

When compiling a rust library using `crate_type = ["staticlib"]`, no PDB is produced on Windows using the MSVC toolchain.

- Is it possible to debug (step into) rust code when called from C++ without a PDB?
- Is there a way to force the rust compiler to emit a PDB for my static library?